# How to Use [XmlElement(DataType="date")] with WebMethod Attribute of a WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

My Web Service Signature is

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetPatientLastWeighing(int pFacilityID,string pSessionID)
{
}
```

Comment: So, given a DataSet, an int and a string, what exactly do you want to treat as a date?

Comment: The columns of DataTable coming in the DataSet contains a dateTime Column which gets changed when accessed from a different TimeZone. all I want the Date should come to me as "it is" in the DataBase at Server

Answer (score 3):

You don't have much control over `DataSet`/`DataTable` serialization. IMO, the best answer here is: don't use `DataSet`/`DataTable` on web-services. Personally, I'd declare a class with the properties I need, attribute them as I like, and return an array (`T[]`) or `List<T>` of that type.

Far cleaner, you have more control over the xml, and it is usable from different types of client (not just .NET).